# Keyboard + Mouse not working

Tags: keyboard

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 and noticed that immediately after boots up I can not log in Ubuntu because my mouse and my keyboard are not working. I have managed to log in anyway because my trackpad is working (Lenovo Yoga 7 Slim Pro). My built in keyboard and my external mouse are not working. The strange thing is that my external keyboard is working.

I have tried the command with xorg-input-all, I do not remember the command exactly.

If I wait like 3-4 minutes in the log-in page or if I log in and wait another 2-3 minutes, everything starts working normally. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

The only things that worked is the following line:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nopnp=1 i8042.dumbkbd=1"

Adding "i8042.nopnp=1 i8042.dumbkbd=1" and my lag disapeared.